# Varnish cache with 302 redirection

Tags: redirect, varnish, http-status-code-302

I have a problem with varnish when my wordpress redirect a page with 302 status.

My environment :
  Varnish listening on IP1:80
  Backend (Apache) listening on IP2:80
  Site type : wordpress

Concidering two pages : 
  **page1**, **page2**

I have configured a 302 redirection in wordpress from **page1** to **page2**.

But even if **page2** is already cached by varnish, 
when **page2** is requested after 302 redirection, 
varnish doesn't deliver content from the cache but send the request to the backend !

So what is the problem ? 
How can I fix it ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cache page1 response.

I guess your backend is sending some kind of no-cache, max-age or expires header that prevents Varnish caching of the response, since default behaviour is tu cache 302 status codes [1].

Please attach varnishlog of a full request of page1 along with your VCL configuration.

[1] https://www.varnish-software.com/static/book/VCL_Basics.html#the-initial-value-of-beresp-ttl